# What is this symbol?

Tags: knowledge, symbols

No backstory or hints here. Just a symbol.
[image: quite a strange one]
What does this symbol mean?

Any theories are welcome too.

Comment: Is that your wrist?

Comment: @AvZ does matter ?

Comment: It might be pure imagination of the person who has it on his/her wrist of right hand.
It does look like an inverted Psi (Greek symbol) with leaves drawn from it.

Comment: @Shafizadeh I was going to ask him if it's a puzzle about his tattoo or just a general question to help him identify (his friend's?) tattoo.

Comment: That's a symbol my friend drew on me and refused to tell me what it is. It is confirmed to be a chineese symbol. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think it is ...

> Early form of an **Chinese letter**

Also here is a photo of it:

> [image]

BTW, It looks like a ancient pictograms either. I don't know, maybe if you [google it](https://www.google.lv/search?q=ancient+pictograms&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr2ZzChrbJAhVC8XIKHXg_CvQQ_AUIBygB&biw=1408&bih=692) then you find some similar symbol.